# Reflections on tomcat server from the outside

Tags: java, tomcat, reflection

As part of a challenge, I would like to use reflections to get information about the code running on a tomcat server as *.jsp. (Assuming that the server is not configured very secure and allows this).

Google shows absolutely no answer regarding tomcat and reflections from the outside.

I guess I might have to combine it with Remote Procedure Calls or sth like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't get free exploits just because Java has reflection.

Reflection (as in `java.lang.reflect.*`) works only from the inside. Code executing in a JVM process can reason about other code running in the same context, IOW, the program can reflect about itself.

You would need to be able to inject your spying code into the server's java process.

Luckily, servers generally don't allow you to do that, not even badly configured ones - unless there is a remote code execution vulnerability like [CVE-2013-4444](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2013-4444) for example.

You also can't abuse Remote Procedure Calls that easy. First of all, a remotely callable procedure must be placed there by the programmer. And there are none by default. But assuming you find something that is for some reason unprotected, you'd still only be allowed to call that procedure, not arbitrary code of your choice. If you can, you've probably found a vulnerability.